# Spring Mvc application PUT request with @ModelAttribute with multipart request form not binding

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, put, modelattribute

I have Spring application that handles REST APIs. All are working well until I converted the XML configuration to annotation configuration. At that time I have a problem in a few APIs. that APIs are PUT request With @ModelAttribute. that ajax requested data not binding in rest request.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT,value="/user")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updatePlanSponsor(@ModelAttribute UserDTO user,BindingResult errors, @CookieValue(value="userID") Long userId){
------
}
```

All other requests like PUT with application/JSON, POST with multipart/form-data;
 In case of PUT with multipart/form-data; form not binding in dto class

Comment: Have you tried this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19608161/2746919

Comment: I can't change it to form data submit to json submit in client-side.. because its already in production. Its error since from I converted the XML configuration to annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did to mistaken to add multi part resolver. 
PUT request with multipart only support with `PutAwareCommonsMultipartResolver`. `CommonsMultipartResolver`  not support for PUT with Multipart .

```
 public class PutAwareCommonsMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

    private static final String MULTIPART = "multipart/";

    @Override
    public boolean isMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request != null && isMultipartContent(request);
    }

    /**
     * Utility method that determines whether the request contains multipart
     * content.
     * 
     * @param request The servlet request to be evaluated. Must be non-null.
     * 
     * @return <code>true</code> if the request is multipart; {@code false}
     * otherwise.
     * 
     * @see ServletFileUpload#isMultipartContent(HttpServletRequest)
     */
    public static final boolean isMultipartContent(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String method = request.getMethod().toLowerCase();
        if (!method.equals("post") && !method.equals("put")) {
            return false;
        }
        String contentType = request.getContentType();
        if (contentType == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (contentType.toLowerCase().startsWith(MULTIPART)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```