# How do I get the JSON in a response body with Spring annotaion

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I have a standard Spring 4 MVC application.  I have REST endpoints that take the ResponseBody json and maps to my Java objects.  This is working great.

But now I have a need to get the raw JSON,  as I do not have a Java object to map it to.  My endpoint looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
@ResponseBody
public Object createObject(@RequestBody JsonObject objectJson) {
```

When I POST json to this endpoint I get an empty JSON string.  The objectJson is not NULL,  but when I debug like this:

```
System.out.println(objectJson.toString());
```

I get:  {}

when I change the method signature to:

```
public Object createObject(@RequestBody String objectJson) {
```

I get a 400 "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

How do I get the JSON being sent in,  either as a String that I can parse manually,  or the JsonObject and I can use?

Comment: Have you tried this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16467400/1545775 ?

Comment: RequestBody is missing @

Comment: what does the JSON look like?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including your configuration. At the moment, we can only guess what is wrong and that's not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score -2):

In order to receive a JSON object using `@RequestBody`, you will need to define a POJO class. Suppose your raw JSON looks like

```
{"id":"123", "name":"John"}
```

The POJO will look like

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    ...
    // setters and getters
}
```

Your Controller method will be

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
@ResponseBody
public Object createObject(@RequestBody User user) {
    String id = user.getId();
    String name = user.getName();
    ...
}
```

Comment: How does this explain why `toString()` returns `{}` or the 400 bad request? Assuming they are using Gson's `JsonObject` and a `GsonHttpMessageConverter`, this should work out of the box.

Comment: I never used `@RequestBody` for JsonObject type, it might work, but I am not sure why toString() is empty. For 400 bad request, that's because a JSON payload is expected, but its type is String.

Comment: With `String`, Jackson, by default, should use a `StringHttpMessageConverter` which just takes the request content as text and passes it to your handler method as that `String` argument.