# json postman issue about post image with it's encode image

Tags: java, json, postman

I have an issue with postman json format. I want to post an image with it's encode image to store it in a mongodb instance. But I get an error 400. I have attached the image in formdata and it's encode details in json format. But still I get the same 400 error repeat

**model class**

```
public class Image {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String userId;

    private byte[] image;    

    private String extension;

    private String text;
} /with getters and setter and constructors
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "ocr/v1/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Status doOcr(@RequestBody Image image) throws Exception {
        try {
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream (Base64.decodeBase64 (image.getImage()));
            Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract(); // JNA Interface Mapping
            String imageText = tesseract.doOCR(ImageIO.read(bis));
            image.setText(imageText);
            repository.save(image);
            LOGGER.debug("OCR Result = " + imageText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
     LOGGER.error("TessearctException while converting/uploading image: ", e);
            throw new TesseractException();
        }
        return new Status("success");    }
```

JSON:

```
    {   
        "image": {  
            "userId": "arun0009",   
            "extension": ".png",    
            "text": "WlgSmI3XGrnq31Uy6Vfnuo/qnHz1K8Z1+e4flJXk"
        }
    }
```

CODE:

```java
    @Test
    public void testDoOcr() throws IOException 
    {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.put("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        Image image = new Image();
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("eurotext.png");
        image.setUserId("arun0009");
        image.setExtension(".png");
        image.setImage(Base64.encodeBase64(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)));
        String response = given().contentType("application/json").headers(headers).body(image).when().post("http://localhost:8080/ocr/v1/upload").then()
            .statusCode(200).extract().response().body().asString();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

> "status": 400,
>       "error": "Bad Request",
>       "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.tess4j.rest.model.Image` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.tess4j.rest.model.Image` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
>       "path": "/ocr/v1/upload"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really think that your issue is in conversion. try to use annotations like that to ignore the fields that you aren't passing in JSON:

```
@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty(value = "user_password")
public String userPassword;
```

References: [Ignore fields from Java object dynamically while sending as JSON from Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc).

---

EDIT

Your Image class could have a "private string imageReceived"(Base64String) and a "private byte[] image". You could receive a string and decrypt to a byte[]. HTTP Transactions can only pass string values by the way you're already converting, you only need to receive this string value in the Web API

Comment: Yes, tried with that one also but same error repeat

Comment: how does your back-end code work? I guess that can also be a problem in json conversion to an object

Comment: Well, I really thing that your issue is in conversion. Try to use annotations like that to ignore the fields that you arent passing in json:

@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty(value = "user_password")
public String userPassword;

References: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101260/ignore-fields-from-java-object-dynamically-while-sending-as-json-from-spring-mvc

Comment: I was applied this @Jsonignore and JsonProperty for the field which is not used in json conversion[postman] but the error still exist . bad request and internal server error. I couldn't found that exact way to pass field in postman. I was added image and it's encode details in postman but it's not accept the json format. I was applied many stack overflow suggestion on this topic but won't works.  SOURCE URL:  https://github.com/arun0009/ocr-tess4j-rest

Comment: So since the problem is not some unmapped field, you can use a base64StringImage field for example, because I think error could be related to the field type, it must be trying to parse an array and found a string.

Comment: base64StringImage field means , shall I add additional string type image filed in my image class or add  base64String in postman request ?. Because already i have "image" byte  field  name in my image class. So additional can't add with same name it must be a "private String image1" only. Same filed name in same class not possible.  I was tried out with Map interface in this case but won't solve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467035/spring-mvc-doesnt-deserialize-json-request-body/16467400

Comment: Your Image class could have a "private string imageReceived"(Base64String) and a "private byte[] image". You could receive a string and decrypt to a byte[]. HTTP Transactions can only pass string values by the way you're already converting, you only need to receive this string value in the Web API